# Why is my function override for STL class function used even for wrong argument type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, overload-resolution

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

class MyStack : public std::stack<double>
{
public:
    void push(char)
    {
        std::cout << "Using char overload of push function.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStack stack{};
    stack.push(3.);   // Why does this call push(char)?
}
```

This program compiles and prints "Using char overload of push function." when run. Why is it so?

I would think that the templated `void push( value_type&& value );` would be used because value_type should be double and so should be better fit when calling push with the double argument 3.

I know I can use std::stack as a member and rewrite functions I need from std::stack to MyStack but inheritance with overloading seemed to be more elegant.

Compiler: gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)

Build command: `g++-11 -std=c++20 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wsign-conversion -Weffc++ -o`

Comment: Your `push` hides the inherited member overloads . you can "unhide" them with using declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers are in the comments and the dup, this code snippet will give you what you want:

```
class MyStack : public std::stack<double>
{
public:
    using std::stack<double>::push;

    void push(char c)
    {
        std::cout << "Using char overload of push function\n";
    }
};
```

And yes, many people (including me) find the way the language is specified to behave in this regard counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thank you. I would expect the code in question to just not compile due to the needed conversion. Isn't double to char a narrowing conversion if such a conversion exists at all?

Comment: The conversion is certainly legal, but you can force an error by writing `stack.push ({3.});`.  Without the braces, neither gcc nor clang issue a warning, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.   This is probably for historical reasons.